# How to redirect index.html to the same name with capital letter by nginx

Tags: nginx

I need to redirect from index.html to Index.html in whole site in any folders deep. How to make this redirect?

Comment: Why not do `index index.html Index.html;` and remove the need for the index.html bit entirely?

Comment: @alex you have multiple options, once is to use the index as above, but for what reason do you use Capital letters? You may take a look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152514/how-do-i-rename-all-folders-and-files-to-lowercase-on-linux in case to solve that

Comment: You can see there may be a good reason to state your objective, as people here are making assumptions about why you are asking this question and suggesting solutions that may not be applicable to your use case.

Comment: @Paul, Reason is simple, I has moved site from Windows to Linux. Site usually has name like Index.htm, but old link to site page look as Index.htm and index.htm and sometimes as INDEX.HTM, because Windows Web Server processing this transformation automatically. But now I decide redirect all old link to new correct link and delete old wrong link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further information on your use case, here is one attempt:

```
location ~ (.*)/index.html$ {
    return 301 $1/Index.html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It working.